# SQL Getting position in database WHERE from array

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm working on a scoreboard which separates from global, region and country. I got global and country working. Here's my code to get the number per country:

```
$euCountries = array('AL', 'AD', 'AM', 'AT', 'BY', etc....);

if (in_array($CountryCode, $euCountries)) { $region = 'EU'; }

$countryRankSql = "SELECT name, FIND_IN_SET(xp, (
         SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(xp ORDER BY xp DESC) 
         FROM users WHERE countrycode = :CountryCode ) ) AS rank 
     FROM users WHERE id = :id";
$countryRankGet = $db->prepare($countryRankSql);
$countryRankGet->execute(array(
 ':CountryCode' => $CountryCode,
 ':id' => $id,
));
$countryRank = $countryRankGet->fetch()['rank'];
```

Now I would like to do the same, but WHERE are multiple CountryCodes from an array (for example $euCountries). So basically the same as the country sql only where `WHERE countrycode = :CountryCode`
is an array of countries.

How am I going to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take that same string, without converting to an array, and use it in your select statement:

```
SELECT name, FIND_IN_SET(xp, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(xp ORDER BY xp DESC) FROM users WHERE countrycode in ($euCountries) ) ) AS rank FROM users WHERE id = :id
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Can i just put array(':euCountries' => $euCountries,); in my execute line?

Comment: I don't know why you would.  The SELECT statement is just a string.  And the list of contries, already in quotes, and comma delimeted, is already correct.  So what's the point?